# is it possible to fill ppt template's fields with excel records

Tags: excel, office365, powerpoint, office-automation

Hi community I have a question so I'm not used to use excel and ppt and now I need to figure out a time saving method to this problem:

so I have a ppt template with a bunch of fields that should be filled with  records from excel . I have more than 100 records so I have to repeat this processe 100 time ,copy past the data into this template

**> the question there is any way to avoid this repetitive process ?**

**I give an example to be more clear :**
suppose I have in the ppt a field where I put the ***id***  ,a field for the ***name*** and an other for ***last name*** .
I have excel sheet full of records like that

what I need :by writting the id in the ppt all the information should be filled
or If u know how to create for all the records a template filled with the informations

I will appreciate so much your answers thanks for your time and please ask for more information if you need it

Comment: if you know any api to do that also please you can provide it ,it may help

Comment: This can certainly be done with VBA (part of both PowerPoint and Excel). It's not a beginner project but someone with moderate VBA and google skills should be able to pull it off.  Or there are a couple of inexpensive PowerPoint add-ins that will do the job for you.  Since you're just talking about text, John Wilson's Simple Merge should be all you need:  http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/Simple_merge.html

Comment: If you want to code yourself, here is some overview where to start among the myriads of tutorials and recommendations out there in the internet https://slidefab.com/how-to-create-powerpoint-slides-from-excel-using-vba/ and if you prefer to use a tool, here is a list, too: https://slidefab.com/tools-for-exporting-or-connecting-from-excel-to-powerpoint/